# What are these numbers in the logs? "Nov 19 11:06:42 [redacted]/web.7: 10111111166611[error] 19:06:42 ..."

Tags: heroku, logback, slf4j

Here are some more examples:

```
Nov 19 11:06:42 [redacted] app/web.7: 10111111166611[error] 19:06:42 c.TransactionController - [redacted].
Nov 19 10:50:02 [redacted] app/web.3: 110111001111111111111111016111[warn] 18:50:02 c.BrowseController - [redacted] 
Nov 19 06:13:58 [redacted] app/web.2: 1101111111110[warn] 14:13:57 c.TransactionController - [redacted]
Nov 19 05:33:26 [redacted] app/web.4: 111111111111111111001011[error] 13:33:26 c.TransactionController -[redacted]
Nov 19 05:11:32 [redacted] app/web.3: 1111111111111111011[warn] 13:11:32 c.TransactionController - [redacted] 
Nov 19 04:42:30 [redacted] app/web.8: 01111111110111111110110[error] 12:42:30 c.TransactionController - [redacted] 
Nov 19 03:26:09 [redacted] app/web.4: 11011111006660000[error] 11:26:09 c.TransactionController - [redacted]
```

It started showing in my logs roughly since yesterday.

My app is deployed on Heroku, and we use slf4j and logback. The logs are sent to Papertrails.

At first, I thought it was a binary number, but then there are 6s.

Anyone has intelligent guesses what they are? Thank you.

Edit: Here's my log config:

```
<configuration>

  <conversionRule conversionWord="coloredLevel" converterClass="play.api.libs.logback.ColoredLevel" />

  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%coloredLevel %date{HH:mm:ss} %logger{15} - %message%n%xException{10}</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <appender name="ASYNCSTDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </appender>

  <logger name="com.avaje.ebean.config.PropertyMapLoader" level="OFF" />
  <logger name="com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.XmlConfigLoader" level="OFF" />
  <logger name="com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.lib.BackgroundThread" level="OFF" />
  <logger name="com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript" level="OFF" />/>
  <logger name="com.zaxxer.hikari" level="OFF" />

  <logger name="play" level="INFO" />
  <logger name="application" level="INFO" />
  <logger name="play.api.db.evolutions" level="DEBUG" />

  <root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="ASYNCSTDOUT" />
  </root>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Can you show your logback configuration file?

Comment: I've added it. Thank you. It looks normal to me though.

Comment: Wait a min. This means Papertrails is the one who adds these strange numbers. Because my log config start with %coloredLevel

Comment: Actually, the strange numbers show up since Heroku. So, Papertrails isn't related to this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing %coloredLeve.  It looks like something doesn't understand the color escaping.

Comment: I've changed it to %level, but the strange numbers still show. However, it only shows for the ERROR-level log now. For %coloredLevel, the strange numbers show up for the WARN- and ERROR-level logs. Do you happen to know what those numbers are? Why do they compose of 0,1,and 6?

Comment: No I don't know what it is, but I saw that %coloredLevel is the first thing in your pattern definition, which needs the numbers are either coming from %coloredLevel itself, or from the processing of the platform (heroku).  What about if you remove the 'conversionRule'